# PayPal NVP/SOAP API TransactionSearchReq Call

Tags: java, soap, paypal, nvp

I am currently trying to implement a class in Java that lists all PayPal transactions of a specific time frame. I am using the NVP/SOAP API Merchant SDK (https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java) as this seems to be the only possibility to list 'all' transactions. According to other questions on stackoverflow the REST SDK only lists transactions that were made by REST calls, which is not suitable in my case.

Unfortunately the sample code for a TransactionSearchReq call on github shown in the README file is not complete and there is also no other sample implementation of that call available.

So my questions are:
1) Can anybody help with a sample code?
2) Will the merchant NVP/API SDK fulfill the requirements for the new security updates of PayPal (https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2016/05/12/upcoming-security-changes-notice/ & https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/tls-http-upgrade) taking place by June 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question 1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.*;
import urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.PaymentTransactionSearchResultType;

public class PaymentManager {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String,String> configMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    configMap.put("mode", "live");

    // Account Credential
    configMap.put("acct1.UserName", "...");
    configMap.put("acct1.Password", "...");
    configMap.put("acct1.Signature", "...-...");
    // Subject is optional, only required in case of third party permission
    //configMap.put("acct1.Subject", "");

    // Sample Certificate credential
    // configMap.put("acct2.UserName", "certuser_biz_api1.paypal.com");
    // configMap.put("acct2.Password", "D6JNKKULHN3G5B8A");
    // configMap.put("acct2.CertKey", "password");
    // configMap.put("acct2.CertPath", "resource/sdk-cert.p12");
    // configMap.put("acct2.AppId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");


    TransactionSearchReq txnreq = new TransactionSearchReq();
    TransactionSearchRequestType requestType = new TransactionSearchRequestType();

    requestType.setStartDate("2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"); 
    requestType.setEndDate("2018-04-05T23:59:59.000Z"); 
    requestType.setVersion("95.0");
    requestType.setTransactionID("");
    txnreq.setTransactionSearchRequest(requestType);

    PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(configMap);

    try {
        TransactionSearchResponseType txnresponse = service.transactionSearch(txnreq, configMap.get("acct1.UserName"));

        List<PaymentTransactionSearchResultType> transactions = txnresponse.getPaymentTransactions();

        for (int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(transactions.get(i).getPayer());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```